# Why do Android browsers (Chrome/stock) force twitter intents to close then open in the same window, even when _blank or window.open are used?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, twitter, webintents

Example of what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/dtipson/ttebddd5/2/

In all other browsers, and in cases not linking to twitter's intents pages, when you open a new window or target blank, it opens in a new tab. But with android, even once you've set the browser to handle links to twitter.com, the new window opens, then immediately closes, and then the original (calling) page navigates to twitter.com. Example code that won't work properly (though I doubt it's anything to do with this):

```
window.open(
            'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=hi',
            'intent',
'scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=yes,status=no,width=550,height=420');
```

My guess is that this has something to do with have Android handles "application intents": if a page redirects to something that claims to have a native application link, it looks back up the chain of window.opener and affects the original page instead.

To try and block this behavior, I've tried using window.open to open a page that waits a few seconds and THEN redirects to twitter.com/intents.  But even here, the new tab opens, waits for however many seconds on that transition page, and then right when it redirects, it closes itself and the original tab redirects to twitter.com instead.  I've tried setting window.opener to null (even though that shouldn't do anything).  I'm not sure how any code on twitter.com could even affect the original page as they are obviously not on the same domain (and I've tried setting things up so that the original domain does NOT have twitter's widgets.js on it, so they can't be using POSTMessage).

This really seems to be a (imho, bad) )quirk with how Android handles intents.  Anyone know of any workarounds?